# Selenium java I have issue with two method that are failed, there is no any error shown in code but Two cases are failed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, browser-automation

> I have issue with title verification & close browser method both are failed, there is no any error shown in code but 2 case are failed..

> **This is my code**

```
    package com.google;
            
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
            
    public class Titlevarification {
                
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void Launchbrowser() throws InterruptedException 
    {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\New folder 
    (3)\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
                          
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }     
                      
    @Test(priority=2)
    public static void titlevarification(WebDriver driver)
    {
    String ExpectedTitle = "Google";
    String ActualTitle = driver.getTitle();
                     
    if (ActualTitle.equals(ExpectedTitle)) 
    {
    System.out.println("Test Passed!");
    } 
    else 
    {
    System.out.println("Test Failed");
    }
    }
    @Test(priority=3)
    public static void closebrowser(WebDriver driver)
    {
    driver.quit();
    System.out.println("Browser Closed");
    }
    }
```

> **these are errors**
> PASSED: Launchbrowser FAILED: titlevarification
> org.testng.TestNGException:  Cannot inject @Test annotated Method
> [titlevarification] with [interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver].
> For more information on native dependency injection please refer to
> https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
> at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:439)
> at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParametersForMethod(Parameters.java:353)
> at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:708)
> at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:884)
> at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:740)
> at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:59)
> at
> org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:38)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:791)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
> at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
> at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> ## FAILED: closebrowser
> org.testng.TestNGException:  Cannot inject @Test
> annotated Method [closebrowser] with [interface
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]. For more information on native
> dependency injection please refer to
> https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
> at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:439)
> at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParametersForMethod(Parameters.java:353)
> at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:708)
> at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:884)
> at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:740)
> at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:59)
> at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:38)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:791)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
> at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
> at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> Default test
> Tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Skips: 0
> ===============================================
> ===============================================
> Default suite
> Total tests run: 3, Passes: 1, Failures: 2, Skips: 0
> ===============================================

Comment: `@Test` methods don't take arguments (unless parameterized, maybe?). Closing the browser seems not like a test case but rather an `@AfterClass` method. Along the same lines `Launchbrowser` should probably be a `@BeforeClass` method instead of a `@Test`; seems like you misuse priorities for this. Tests should never print whether they failed or succeeded, they should `assert...` something to that the test framework can check what failed and what passed. Finally please use indentation and follow Java naming conventions to make your code easier to understand.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Passing arguments to methods annotated with `@Test` should be done in a special way. I suggest that you remove the `WebDriver` argument from both methods and make it an instance variable instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).